# Where to sleep while touring southern Ontario?

Tags: touring, canada

I've been on-and-off planning a (reasonably) short bike tour from the Kitchener area (about 100km west of Toronto, in Canada) to Ottawa/Montreal, followed by a train ride home. I know most of what I need, but the one thing I haven't got figured out is where to stay. I don't have a ton of money and am an experienced camper, which means I'll lean very heavily towards a tent over a motel/hotel where possible.

I know, however, that my route of choice (east along Lake Ontario from Toronto to Kingston, then northwards to Ottawa, and paralleling the Ottawa River to Montreal) is heavily developed and urbanized, which makes camping problematic at best. Canada, rather unfortunately, don't have anything like the [freedom to roam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_to_roam), which means that, unless I secure specific permission from a landowner, I'm trespassing.

Has anyone here been touring in similar circumstances? What are my best options for a (mostly) stress-free night's sleep in areas like this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better asked on http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called Wiki camps which is great for finding campgrounds and works offline.

For free places to camp Community fields can be good. I met a couple guys yesterday who said they have had good luck with firestations, they've not been told no yet when they ask.

There’s also a free camping website which is geared towards RV parking but does have some tent listings. If you google free camping you'll find it.

Lastly Ontario does allow you to camp on Crown land though I'm not sure in that part of Ontario there would be any to be found.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used them, but there is an organization called [Warm Showers](https://www.warmshowers.org/). They say

> The Warm Showers Community is a free worldwide hospitality exchange for touring cyclists.

They claim over 90,000 active members and over 41,000 active hosts.

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: That's perilously close to a link-only answer, I'm not sure a random photo improves it. Surely warm spammers is not the only option?

Comment: @Móż This answer quotes from the site, and the photo is from the site also. I'm guessing it's the Rockies, but it could be any where in the Americas. I don't think such a question should be shipped off to another site. Essentially, it's about cycling, so it belongs here.

Comment: But it's about free camping, not just cycling.

Comment: Nothing is just about cycling